# Statistics regarding MonoTouch usage?

Tags: iphone, mono, statistics, xamarin.ios

Just wondered how many application are written with MonoTouch and published in App Store?

Is MonoTouch ready to be used in production?

What other statistics do you know regarding this tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Chrisntr pointed above, yes, there are a lot of apps already in the appstore, and http://monotouch.info is your place to find them.

Regarding being ready for production, though, I would expand on that a little bit: yes, MonoTouch is ready to create applications that can be deployed with success in the appstore, and can create applications that are just as pretty and fast as obj-c ones.

But developer experience is still not quite there. It's close to being great, but there are things here and there that cause a lot of pain. For example, its not uncommon to have your app all of a sudden crash during startup and require a kill from the command line, or even a reboot of the computer to get it going again. From my experience, this will probably happen at least a couple of times a day. Also, MonoDevelop is simply not as good as eclipse or Visual Studio - too many bugs, not enough functionality, unfortunately.

On the other side, the Novell guys are really really great: they stay around on IRC for most of the day, and help with any bugs right away, most of the times creating patches for you in a matter of minutes. I haven't had this level of support from any other vendor before.

**Update 4/6/2010:** Well, I just updated to the new version 2 of MonoTouch and MonoDevelop, and things actually improved quite a lot. The crashing seems to be gone (although it did happen one time today, but I didn't need to reboot), and many other bugs I had found were also fixed. The Novell guys keep doing a great job updating everything, and this update definitely made things a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

There are a list of applications using MonoTouch on the App Store here - http://monotouch.info/MonoTouch/Apps

This doesn't mean that there isn't many more - especially those that are ad-hoc distributed will not show up on the App Store.

In terms of it being production ready then it sure is.

Answer (score 2):

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uS_9nwdzfzM) (around 0:20:30) is said that 500 applications in App Store are built with mono (however this can include apps build also with Unity stuff, not just MonoTouch).

[Here](http://monotouch.net/Releases) is a list which includes "full releases" so it should be production ready.